# Pandas - Delete all consecutive rows except the first one which share same column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Data-Frame like following:

```
A B C D
- - - -
h e l 0
t h i 0
i s m 0
q u e 1
s t i 1
```

I want to delete all the rows that have same value in `D` consecutively but leaving the first one. The result will be following:

```
A B C D
- - - - 
h e l 0
q u e 1
```

So, far I've done it using following code:

```
df[list(map(lambda x: (x == 0) or (df['D'][x] != df['D'][x-1]), range(len(D))))]
```

I'm wondering if there a better way to do this?

Comment: @jezrael this looks different than the one you marked duplicate against. The OP wants consecutive duplicates to be removed

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan - added new dupe...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use -

```
df.loc[df['D'].shift(1) != df['D']]
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C   D
0   h   e   l   0
3   q   u   e   1
```

Comment: I fear this won't work if `0` occurs more than 2 times. Right?

Comment: @Lokesh didn't get you. I tried it against OP's example which contains 3 consecutive duplicates and it worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Working without a problem! You rock